# Realtime refresh after deleting data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a button to delete amounts, and I have a textview with total amount, but when I delete amounts the textview with the total does not update, it only does if I go to another activity and come back, why is it? any ideas?

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Expenses").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    reference.child(postId).removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

        Expense expenseBackUp = new Expense(item, category, date, postId, amount);

        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Snackbar.make(rv, item + " has been deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        reference.child(postId).setValue(expenseBackUp);
                    }
                }).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ExpensesActivity.this, "Something went wrong, try again" + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Is any of the Toast or Snackbar messages displayed?

Comment: yes, the snackbar works and the amount removes, it just not updating until I go to another activity, but it does perform the deletion, weir thing is that if I update the amount to increment instead of deleting it does update my textview total amount.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `.setValue(expenseBackUp)` operation to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: that setValue is just for the "undo" action button and it works fine, the issue is when deletion is complete textview with amount should subtract the amount deleted in realtime.